# jquery dblclick event can not stop event propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have double click event handler on div, and click event handler on button, that is child of the div.
but when i click on the button 2 times, div's dblclick event happens (see http://jsfiddle.net/9dcSk/3/ ).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/bs21/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body,html {
                background:yellow;
            }
            .myDiv {
                background:pink;
                padding:40px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready( function() {
                $('div.myDiv').click( function() {
                    console.log('div dbl clicked');
                } );
                $('button.myButton').click( function(event) {
                    console.log('button clicked');
                } );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=myDiv>test<button class=myButton>ok</button></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was trying to add `e.stopPropagation()` to click event, but this doesnt helps.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: when I click on button no div's dblclick event must happens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you should be doing is to return false on **button double click** before the div call.

That is:

```
$('button.myButton').click( function(e) {
    $('div#log').append('<div>btn clicked</div>');
});
$('button.myButton').dblclick( function(e) {
    return false
});
$('div.myDiv').dblclick( function(e) {
    $('div#log').append('<div>div dblclicked</div>');
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/javascript/9dcSk/5/

Answer (score 0):

This could do the trick.

```
   $('div.myDiv').dblclick( function(e) {
      if(e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON" ){
                return false;
         }
    $('div#log').append('<div>div dblclicked</div>');
    });

   $('button.myButton').click( function(e) {
      $('div#log').append('<div>btn clicked</div>');
   });
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LDdHG/)